# How can I get the Snowball artifact?

Tags: demoncrawl

[The wiki](https://demoncrawl.com/wiki/index.php?title=Stages) lists the Snowball as coming from one of the "other stages", specifically the "Christmas" stage. I haven't seen that stage anywhere. How can I play that stage? Can I get that artifact any other way, like as a reward from completing a Beyond quest?

Answer (score 1):

The snowball artifact (and all other Christmas-associated items) were part of a time-limited Christmas event. [As mentioned in a December update on Steam](https://steamdb.info/patchnotes/4503189/):

> Those of you have unlocked Hard Mode will be able to find new **Snowball artifacts**. Use Snowballs in a Beyond recipe to access the **special Christmas stage**.

They clarify in [a later update](https://steamcommunity.com/games/1141220/announcements/detail/1690470748504707200) that the drops will be available again, but I cannot tell if they include the snowballs and associated stage or only the holiday rewards in their idea of what's available:

> We wanted to let you know that DemonCrawl's Christmas Event will be coming to a close soon, on Tuesday, December 31st at around 4 PM EST... There are only a couple days left to unlock your special holiday items! If you miss this opportunity, worry not - you will be able to find the same items again next year in the form of Beyond Mode drops.

Comment: Sadly, I've won probably 80+ Beyond Runs, and I've never gotten a single snowball.